# Regex for zero to multiple range like these: "[12,128]" / "[45,545][7445,78656]"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a Regex to valid a string variable following these conditions:

- 0 to X ranges
- a range looks like this: [num1,num2]
- a number could have 5 digits max

I have this one currently: `/((\[[0-9]{1,5},[0-9]{1,5}\])*)/`

But when I try it with string `[4,5][14,455]` on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/tL1yJ9/2

It outputs `[4,5][14,455]` and `[14,455]`

Instead of what I want: `[4,5]` and `[14,455]`

I think I'm not far from what I want but don't know what's missing!

Comment: Just [`/\[[0-9]{1,5},[0-9]{1,5}\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/nE6tT1/1) should be what you need. If you mean to also match strings like `[12,234,4567]`, use [`\[[0-9]{1,5}(?:,[0-9]{1,5})+\]`](https://regex101.com/r/nE6tT1/2)

Comment: "0 to X" ranges means that literally any string will match.  For example, the string `foo bar` matches the condition of "0 to X ranges", as there are 0 ranges in that string.

Comment: What are you talking about Paul L?? His question mentions nothing about free text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple regex like `/\[\d{1,5},\d{1,5}\]/g`

```js
console.log(
  '[4,5][14,455]'.match(/\[\d{1,5},\d{1,5}\]/g)
)
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/eM1bB0/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

Amended your regex to include g to work globally, not just the first element it finds.

```
/((\[[0-9]{1,5},[0-9]{1,5}\])*)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/tL1yJ9/3

Comment: his question states a range is [num1,num2] not [num1,num2,num(n)]

Comment: as it is written in English it is open to interpretation, and I read that as 0 - x of [range1],[range2],[rangex], where a range is [num1,num2]